# Perl, issue converting time stamp to readable date

Tags: perl

I have the following one liner, this should convert the date from one week ago today to a readable format.

`my $week_ago = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time - 604800);`

However I get the following error:

```
Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)
```

Can anyone suggest what the issue is here? From my understanding, `strftime` should convert a time stamp to a readable date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As your error message says**, POSIX's `strftime` takes a list of vaules, not a unix timestamp. You need to call [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) or [`gmtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) before you call it.

```
 my $one_minute_ago = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime(time - 60));
```

The above example is fine if you are doing date math with short amounts below one day. Everything above that is error-prone. For your *one week ago* scenario, use [sobrique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433818/1331451) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Time::Piece`.  It's a core module that replaces `localtime` (and `gmtime`) but turns it into a much more useful form.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $week_ago = localtime() - 604800;
print $week_ago -> strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Note - both `localtime` and `gmtime` now return a `Time::Piece` object, which means you can do numeric comparisons with it too.

You can also for clarity - import `Time::Seconds` and use it to define more useful constants (like `ONE_DAY` and `ONE_WEEK`) as noted by Borodin in the comments.

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw ( ONE_WEEK ); 
my $week_ago = localtime() - ONE_WEEK;
```

Comment: or gmtime instead of localtime, depending what you want

Comment: Also `use Time::Seconds 'ONE_WEEK'` and `localtime( time - ONE_WEEK )`

Comment: Doing math on epoch times such as `localtime( time - 604800 )` and `localtime( time - ONE_WEEK )` do is wrong; it sometimes give the incorrect result. Only performing arithmetic on the Time::Piece object is safe. Fixed.